# Validate and select entity set data in LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have an entity set, that contain
    name,
    id, 
    start_date 
    end_date. 
 I need to get all the records that should have start date greater than '1-1-2014' and end date should be(start date + 3 months)

Is it possible to select that record with a single LINQ query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean end date should be greater than 3 months after start date?

Comment: `var query = context.YourEntitySet.Select(x => x.start_date > new DateTime(2014, 1, 1)) && x.end_date == x.start_Date.AddMonths(-3)).ToList()`

Comment: @chridam I think you have your dates mixed up

Comment: Yes. End date should be grater than 3 month. That's how data is populated in DB.

Comment: @DavidG Oh yeah, cheers for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
var result = from r in db.Table
             where r.start_date > date
             && r.start_date.AddMonths(3) == r.end_date
             select r
```